# How to do operations on different strings having different types in python2?

Tags: string, python-2.7

Is it wrong to perform operations on strings when one of the them is str type and the other one is unicode type?

Examples:

```
image_url = u"http://sample.com"

# since the iamge url is an unicode string

if image_url.startswith("//"):
    image_url = "https://" + image_url    // combining str type with a unicode string
```

or

```
image_url = "http://sample.com"
if image_url.startswith(u"//"):
    image_url = "https://" + image_url
```

or

```
image_url = "http://sample.com"
if image_url.startswith("//"):
    image_url = u"https://" + image_url
```

or replacing a string using regex:

```
cleaned_breadcrumb = re.sub(r"[^A-Za-z0-9>|]+", u"", u"sample text")
```

or

```
cleaned_breadcrumb = re.sub(r"[^A-Za-z0-9>|]+", "", u"sample text")
```

or

```
cleaned_breadcrumb = re.sub(r"[^A-Za-z0-9>|]+", u"", "sample text")
```

or

```
d = {u"one":"two"}

if "one" in d:
    print("yes")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are subclasses of `BaseString`, so no. As you have discovered, a mixed-type expression will get coerced to unicode. While it is not wrong, it may lead to some surprises, especially when doing text IO to a  file. Both those surprises are inherent in the ambiguous nature of the data in a Python 2 string. The only full solution is to move to Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

It's not technically illegal, but it's a sure way to make your code harder to maintain (wrt/ readability and predictability). In Python2, the safest best is the "unicode sandwich" pattern: decode all text inputs (files / IO / http requests and responses / sys args / user inputs etc) to unicode ASAP, have **all** your program  code working only and exclusively on unicode strings, and encode back to byte strings (with the desired encoding) just before output.